# Mobile front-end to the chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

I am stuck using Opera Mini a lot of the time when I visit http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. But it's annoying to write some long sentence only to have it erased. Would it be possible to either:

- Have a mobile front-end
- or create an API so that *I* can make a mobile front-end.

Comment: I'll tag this [status-completed], but everyone should be aware that in the particular case of Opera Mini, the chat can never work, since the so-called "Turbo Mode" executes the JavaScript on the server once, and then gives you the result. So this isn't really a JavaScript-enabled browser in the actual sense, which would obviously be necessary for the chat to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This already exists. We have a very simplified mobile version that automatically gets displayed when the user is on Android or iPhone.

Since we haven't tested it with Opera Mini, we don't show it automatically. If you take the room link and append `?mobile=true` to it, you'll see it. Please be sure to give feedback if it works, so we can add this browser to the mobile version list.

Comment: Uhm... how do I enter the text? Screenshot: http://imgur.com/SolnQ

Comment: enter key should work, but apparently doesn't -- I'll add a send button. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192/testing-opera-mobile

Comment: It works great now!

Answer (score 1):

Just a further note; we plan to improve many of the other key screens for mobile too; room list, user list, etc. But the core chat screen should work.