# Chat on an Android phone in Chrome mobile renders funny

Tags: discussion, chat

[image]

Self-explanatory. Need I say more?

Comment: So, this is the *desktop* version, right?

Answer (score 2):

The desktop version of chat is not meant to be viewed on a mobile device. Use the mobile version.

If it doesn't automatically go to mobile, your mobile browser may not be tested/compatible, but you [can get there manually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61755/mobile-front-end-to-the-chat) (there's also a "mobile" link in the bottom right corner of the chat window).

Comment: IIRC the mobile version lacks of some *necessary* features such as the *reply to message* and *see what this message is referred to*.

Comment: @Jeffrey: That doesn't make the desktop version magically compatible.

Comment: The mobile lacks of some *important* functionality and the desktop version is broken on mobile (at least for Scott is). Don't you consider this a problem that deserves a better answer than: just use the mobile version (which is what your answer can be summed up to)?

Comment: @Jeffrey: No, I don't. Because the desktop version is not and never was designed to *work* on a mobile device. It's built to work on desktop browsers. Trying to make it work on mobile devices will only introduce other problems in the desktop browsers it's meant to be compatible with. I can direct you to [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) if you want...

Comment: All in all, the *correct* action is feature requests to get those features in the mobile version, not hacking the desktop version to work on a mobile browser.

Comment: Are you saying that we should open a new question (feature request post) for those things to get implemented in the mobile version?

Comment: @Jeffrey: My quick search reveals [Add functionality to mobile chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175832/add-functionality-to-mobile-chat) - Seems to cover those things?

Comment: Right, thanks for your time.